# Open AI Gym Observation Space shape Problem

Tags: python, numpy, reinforcement-learning, openai-api

Im trying to solve the Yatzee game once and forever using reinforcement learning. Sadly when i check the gyms conformity with stable baselines, it is critisizing the shape of my observation space. So ive put a print statement in the constructor thats telling me the shape of my observation space, as soon as i create an object.

```
class YatzeeEnv{
    game_state = np.zeros(19, np.int32)

    def __init__(self):
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(19)
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.MultiDiscrete(19)

        for x in self.game_state_adresses:
            self.game_state[x] = -1
        self.reroll()
        self.game_state[self.reroll_state] = 0
        print(self.game_state.shape)
        print(self.observation_space.shape)
}

a = YatzeeEnv()
```

Sadly the output of this is

```
np array shape: (19,)
Observation space shape: ()
```

Why is this? I thought `gym.spaces.MultiDiscrete(19)` defines the observation space as int array with 19 values.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs...

```
This represents the cartesian product of arbitrary :class:`Discrete` spaces.
    It is useful to represent game controllers or keyboards where each key can be represented as a discrete action space.
    Note:
        Some environment wrappers assume a value of 0 always represents the NOOP action.
    e.g. Nintendo Game Controller - Can be conceptualized as 3 discrete action spaces:
    1. Arrow Keys: Discrete 5  - NOOP[0], UP[1], RIGHT[2], DOWN[3], LEFT[4]  - params: min: 0, max: 4
    2. Button A:   Discrete 2  - NOOP[0], Pressed[1] - params: min: 0, max: 1
    3. Button B:   Discrete 2  - NOOP[0], Pressed[1] - params: min: 0, max: 1
    It can be initialized as ``MultiDiscrete([ 5, 2, 2 ])`` such that a sample might be ``array([3, 1, 0])``.
    Although this feature is rarely used, :class:`MultiDiscrete` spaces may also have several axes
    if ``nvec`` has several axes:
    Example::
        >> d = MultiDiscrete(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
        >> d.sample()
        array([[0, 0],
               [2, 3]])
```

If you have only one action space, you dont have to use MultiDiscrete. Or use MultiDiscrete([19]).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer:) sadly applying this, leads to following outout:
`def __init__(self):
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(19)
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.MultiDiscrete([19])

        for x in self.game_state_adresses:
            self.game_state[x] = -1
        self.reroll()
        self.game_state[self.reroll_state] = 0
        print("np array shape: " + str(self.game_state.shape))
        print("Observation space shape: " + str(self.observation_space.shape))`

Output
np array shape: (19,)
Observation space shape: (1,)

Comment: 'import gym
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from stable_baselines3.common.env_checker import check_env